# Unable to mock a function in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to mock a function used within the function I'm testing, but for some reason I'm not seeing the original function always runs, not the one I created as a mock.

The code I'm testing has this type of setup:

```
def function_being_tested(foo):
    ...
    function_i_want_to_mock(bar)
    ...

def function_i_want_to_mock(bar)
    print("Inside original function")
    ...
```

I've installed Mock and I've tried using unittest.mock patch

Currently the test file uses this setup:

```
import mock
from django.test import TestCase


def mock_function_i_want_to_mock(bar):
    print(bar)
    return True


class SupportFunctionsTestCases(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("path.to.function.function_i_want_to_mock", mock_function_i_want_to_mock)
    def test_function_being_tested(self):
        # setup
        result = function_being_tested(test_foo)
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result)
```

What then happens is when I run the test, I always get: "Inside original function", not the parameter printed so it's always running the original function.

I've used this exact setup before and it has worked so I'm not sure what's causing this. Probably some wrong setup...

If anyone has a different way of doing this or spots some error, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"path.to.function.function_i_want_to_mock"` should be a path to where the function is used, not defined.

So if `function_i_want_to_mock` is defined in `moduleA.py` but imported and used in `moduleB.py` which you are testing then you should use `@mock.patch("path.to.moduleB.function_i_want_to_mock", ...)`.

Comment: This solved it! In my previous usage of this the inner functions I was testing were in the same module as those I was mocking so this discrepancy was "hidden" to me. Thank you!

Comment: Oh my god, you saved my life! ❤